# using console.table() with jQuery array -- how to not include "extra" jquery properties

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-devtools

i want to console.table() a jquery array like this:

```
console.table($("input").filter(":hidden"), ["name", "value"]);
```

however, the table includes all those extra jquery properties that come along for the ride. is there a "correct" way to not output these extra properties to the table, or should i just populate a new array with (in this example) indices 0-8 and output that?

[image: truncated output of console.table]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery has a `makeArray` function that looks promising.

It should return a JS array with all the elements from the original object:

```
jQuery.makeArray( $("input").filter(":hidden") )
```

See: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.makearray/